# "I have just peeked...and I spot" is my fix for this sentence correct?

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-tense, phrasal-verbs

A friend left a comment in my facebook.
She wrote this:

> I have just peeked your Facebook and I spot your nice photos

I think that she should have written this way:

> I had peeked your Facebook and I spotted your nice photos

Because her spot action should have already finsihed before she left the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write it would be:

> I have just peeked at your Facebook, and I saw your nice photos.

"Spotted" would be acceptable, but it isn't a very natural-sounding way to say "saw" in this context. "Noticed" would probably be better.

Either way, you're correct that "spot" should be in the past tense. The reason is that the main verb phrase "have just peeked" is in the **present perfect tense**, and therefore the second verb should be in the simple past tense to be in agreement. A couple other ways to rewrite the sentence grammatically include:

> I just peeked at your Facebook, and I have seen your nice photos.
>
> I just peeked at your Facebook, and I saw your nice photos.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @kitty You're welcome. Please be sure to mark as answered!